# Prove: There are zero divisors in $\Bbb Z_n$ if and only if $n$ is not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization

I need to prove there are zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $n$ is not prime.
What should I consider first?

Comment: Write down what in means for $k \in \mathbb Z/(n)$ to be a zero divisor. What does this imply for $n$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If $n$ is not prime, then either $n=1$ (in which case this is trivial) or there are some integers $k,m\in\{2,...,n-1\}$ such that $n=km$ (as you've correctly deduced). What can we conclude from there about certain elements of $\Bbb Z_n$?

If $n$ is prime, and $[km]=[k][m]=[0]$ for some $[k],[m]\in\Bbb Z_n,$ then $n\mid km,$ and so...what?

Comment: Thanks. So, if $n$ is not prime, then either $n=1$ or there are some integers $k,m\in\{2,...,n-1\}$ such that $km=n$? I am not following this part "If $n$ is prime, and $[km]=[k][m]=[0]$ for some $[k],[m]\in\Bbb Z_n,$ then $n\mid km,$ and so...what?", If $n$ is prime,to make this $[km]=[k][m]=[0]$, $k=1$, $m=n$ is this what you mean?

Comment: You're right on target with the first part. Do you see how the conclusion follows from there? As for the second part, we don't necessarily need $k=1,m=n.$ Since $n\mid km$ and $n$ is prime, then *by definition of prime* we can conclude that $n\mid k$ or $n\mid m,$ so what can we conclude about $[k]$ or $[m]$?

Comment: Either $k=n$ or $m=n$?...

Comment: Not quite. For example, we may well have $k=3n$ and $m=1.$ The key thing to remember is that $[j]=[k]$ if and only if $n\mid (k-j).$ If $n\mid k=k-0,$ then $[k]=[0],$ and if $n\mid m=m-0,$ then $[m]=[0].$ Since $[k][m]=[0]$ implies $[k]=[0]$ or $[m]=[0],$ it follows that $\Bbb Z_n$ has no zero-divisors when $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way to go about this: to prove that $\mathbb Z_n$ has zero divisors if and only if $n$ is not prime, is the same as showing that $\mathbb Z_n$ has no zero divisors if and only if $n$ is prime. Here, $\mathbb Z_n = \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$.

1. Suppose $\mathbb Z_n$ has no zero divisors. Then, if $a,b\in\mathbb Z_n$, $a\ne 0$, $b\ne 0$, we must have $ab\ne 0$. Suppose $n$ is not prime. Then, $n = pq$ for some integers $p,q$ such that $p < n$ and $q < n$ where $p,q\ne 0$. However, $pq \equiv 0 \bmod n$. This is a contradiction, so $n$ must be prime.
2. Suppose $n$ is prime. Suppose there exist $a,b\in\mathbb Z_n$ such that $ab = 0$ (same as saying $ab \equiv 0 \bmod n$) where $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$. So, $n | ab$. Since $n$ is prime, $n|ab \implies n|a$ or $n|b$. None of these can happen, since $a < n$ and $b < n$. So, $\mathbb Z_n$ has no zero divisors.

Done!